# Return one space in Spring Rest

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am writing the following service:

```
@RequestMapping("/greeting")
@ResponseBody
public Greeting sayHello() {
    Greeting g = new Greeting();
    g.setBody(" ");
    return g;
}
```

and the Greeting attributes:

```
class Greeting { private String title; private String body; ... }
```

If I set body to " " (one space), I get an error 500. Currently I use Spring 3.1.2. I've also have tried to wrap the response like this:

```
public ResponseEntity<Greeting> sayHelloAlternative() {...
```

But I get the same error. Do you know what's happening?

Thank you so much

Comment: show us the complete error stacktrace, is Greeting just a pojo with just some setter and getter  ?

Comment: Thank for the quick response. Unfortunately, tomcat doesn't log anything. I run this method by executing mvn tomcat7:run

Comment: You need to change your log level settings. Make sure you have logging set up correctly and have the Tomcat logs set to DEBUG.

Comment: If you add a value different from " " does it work well ?

Comment: Yeah, any character different from space works fine and even if I trim the string

Comment: Finally I've managed to get the stacktrace:     
    org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: String index out of range: 1 (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->io.baldur.data.Greeting["camelName"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: String index out of range: 1 (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->io.baldur.data.Greeting["camelName"])

Comment: And yes... that's my fault. The Greeting class has a method called getCamelName() which causes a beautiful JsonMappingException. Thank you so much for your tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be interesting for someone. I've added to my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And set logger level to TRACE. This prints much more information to find the final cause.